# BASH background process printings disappearing the prompt line

Tags: linux, bash, echo, background-process

I have a BASH script that runs on bg and print messages to the user when according to system events.
My problem is that after the echo of these messages, the user need to press on the ENTER key in order to  get back to the prompt line.
Adding new line to the printed messages didn't help since it still comes from the bg and not from the user shell.
Does anyone have an elegant & simple solution to get the user back to the prompt line?

I will appreciate any help here..

Comment: I would like to know that as well, it's an feature that can be quite annoying indeed. What can help to reduce the messy output on screen, is to add enough empty lines, before and after ANY output of that screen in the backgroup. But that doesn't remove the need to press enter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't **need** to press enter to get to a prompt. You are **still** at the prompt that was there before the output was printed. Try just entering a command and hitting enter. (You can also hit <kbd>ctrl-l</kbd> to clear the screen instead of hitting enter to input an empty command.)

The problem here is that the background/alternative process has no relationship to the running shell session and so it is simply writing output to wherever the terminal sticks it. The process might be able to use control sequences to control the output location (but I don't know if this actually works).

Other than that there isn't much to be done about this that I'm aware of. And it isn't a problem in any real way.